# finding a basis of the kernel with polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $U=P_3(\mathbb{R})$, be the vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ consisting of polynomials of degree at most 3 in a formal variable $t$. Let $f:U\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be the linear map defined by $f(u)=u'(-2)$, where $u'(-2)$ denotes the derivative of $u$ with respect to $t$ evaluated at $t=-2$

(i) Determine the matrix of $f$ with respect to the basis {$1,t,t^2,t^3$} of $U$ and the basis {$1$} of $\mathbb{R}$.

(ii) Find a basis of $\ker(f)$.

For (i) I got the 1x4 matrix $(0,1,-4,8)$. How do I do part (ii)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note.** The answer to the first part should be $(0,1,-4,\mathbf{12})$.

---

Take any vector $u\in U$, then:
$$u=\alpha_0 + \alpha_1 t + \alpha_2 t^2 + \alpha_3 t^3\quad \Longrightarrow\quad f(u) = \alpha_1 - 4 \alpha_2 + 12\alpha_3$$
Now
$$u\in \ker f \quad \Longrightarrow\quad f(u)=0 \quad \Longrightarrow\quad \alpha_1 - 4 \alpha_2 + 12\alpha_3 = 0$$
Therefore, the coordinates must satisfy $\alpha_1 = 4 \alpha_2 - 12\alpha_3$. Thus
$$\ker f = \{\alpha_0 + (4 \alpha_2 - 12\alpha_3) t + \alpha_2 t^2 + \alpha_3 t^3\ |\ \alpha_0,\alpha_2,\alpha_3\in \mathbb R\}$$
A basis of this subspace is

> $$\{1,\ 4t+t^2,\ -12t+t^3\}$$

Comment: OK ofcourse they are LI but how do we know it spans U? by a theorem im guessing but which one?

Comment: They span $\ker f$, not $U$. If you rewrite the vectors in $\ker f$, you get $\alpha_0 + \alpha_2 (4t+t^2) + \alpha_3(-12t+t^3)$.

Answer (score 1):

Using the rank-nullity theorem we see that the dimension of the kernel is $3$ hence a basis of it consisting of three linearly independent polynomials of image $0$ by $f$. Notice that $u'(-2)=0$ together with $u(-2)=0$ means that $-2$ is at least a double root of $u$ so we can take the basis

$$(1,(t+2)^2,(t+2)^2t)$$